# Nested overlapping subnet to secure hardware administration

Tags: subnet, network

I have a question regarding nested subnets. We have a development environment with ip-range 10.0.0.0\22 and i should secure our hardware.

My first intention was to create a nested subnet 10.0.3.0\24 with all devices to secure and connect it via software-firewall to the 10.0.0.0\22 network (the nested subnet is overlapping). The IP-Range 10.0.3.x will be reserved in the development environment, so there will be no IP conflicts. I would enable NAT and use Port-Forwarding to have access to some specific devices in the nested subnet and the devices in the nested subnet will have access to NTP/DNS/.. in the development environment. If the software-firewall fail, I could easily connect the nested subnet (10.0.3.0\24) to the development network (10.0.0.0\22) and can access the devices in the nested network from our development environment and only have to change the default-gateway and subnet mask of the devices in the nested subnet to access NTP/DNS/..
Additionally I thought it would be possible, to connect the nested subnet directly to the development when the firewall is running.

After some research I found that nested subnet should be avoided and I’m not sure if I can set up pfSense to work with overlapping networks on the WAN and LAN side.

I am looking forward to your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Based on your description (which is a little confusing to me), I don't see why you need NAT.  Is there some other requirement?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusing description. NAT is not required. The firewall should just secure the administration of the devices in the 10.0.3.0\24 subnet.

Comment: You can make this work, but it depends on what's inside the blue cloud.  Is the /22 one subnet or several smaller ones?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, the blue cloud is just one subnet

Comment: Routers route between networks, not from a network to the same network, which is what overlapping networks would be. Trying to configure overlapping networks on two different router ports should cause an error in your router configuration. How for instance, will a router know which interface of two with overlapping networks to use?

Comment: Something along these lines could be accomplished with the use of a private VLAN for the devices in the 10.0.3.0/24. Not sure this would be possible since we don't know any details of the hardware in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest approach: use another subnet that's not within your production network (e.g. 10.0.4.0/24).

Second easiest approach: split 10.0.0.0/22 into (at least) 10.0.0.0/23, 10.0.2.0/24 and 10.0.3.0/24.

Another approach is an L3 ACL on your switches - if they support this. You can allow some source IPs to connect to 10.0.3.0/24 *within the same subnet* while denying all others.

NAT doesn't help you - it works across a router and as long as your clients believe the destination is within the same subnet they won't use a router. You'd need the router to answer ARP requests on behalf of the destination (seemingly in the same subnet) - this is called proxy ARP. Both NAT and proxy ARP are messy and to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a last question. If i would use Port-Forwarding it would be possible to reach some defined services in the nested subnet trough the WAN interface of the firewall (e.g. the WAN IP of the firewall would be 10.0.0.100, i could access the Management-Website of a NAS in the nested subnet through 10.0.0.100:80 if port-forwarding is configured correctly).

Comment: And if there is the need to access other Machines where port forwarding is not configured, it would be possible to connect the nested subnet directly to the 10.0.0.0\24 network and access this machine through the IP 10.0.3.X without changing any configuration in the 10.0.0.0\24 network while the machines in the nested subset would access the 10.0.0.0\24 network through the firewall, or am i wrong? Would there be any troubles?

I don`t know yet if any firewall can be configured like this, but could this also be a solution?

Comment: @phil Port forwarding is possible as long as your router knows where and how to reach the destination device, ie. you sort out the inherent routing problem in your original design. However, I don't _ever_ port forward anything through the firewall that isn't meant for the Internet public - better use VPN access.

Comment: "possible to connect the nested subnet directly to the 10.0.0.0\24 network" - connect directly as in switched/bridged? Possible yes (you can run multiple subnets inside a single L2 segment), but there's no security improvement without separating the subnets.